# Cubit not returning data from Firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, bloc

This is the cubit:

```
class HomeDecksCubit extends Cubit<HomeDecksState> {
  HomeDecksCubit({required this.databaseRepository})
      : super(const HomeDecksState(requested: true)) {
    fetchHomeDecks();
  }
  final DatabaseRepository databaseRepository;
  late StreamSubscription<List<Deck>> decksSubscription;

  void fetchHomeDecks() {
    decksSubscription = databaseRepository.userDecksStream().listen((event) async{
      log.v(event);
      emit(state.copyWith(decks: event, requested: false));
    });
  }

  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    decksSubscription.cancel();
    return super.close();
  }
}
```

fetchHomeDecks always emits an empty list when it should emit some non-empty data.
How to fix it?

Comment: Is the data from event not empty?  What does that log is showing?

Comment: It's fixed by getting data from the stream using .first

  void fetchHomeDecks() {
    decksSubscription =
        databaseRepository.userDecksStream().listen((event) async {
      var data = await databaseRepository.userDecksStream().first;
      emit(state.copyWith(decks: data, requested: false));
    });
  }